# Space between header and menu on Tumblr blog

Tags: css, header, tumblr, space, nav

I recently made some changes to my Optica themed blog on Tumblr; specifically, I changed the height of the header image in the custom css section. Problem is, now I have this huge space between the header and the menu which I can't get rid of. I tried removing parts from the source, but to no avail.

You can see the blog here: http://ilconfess.tumblr.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your height set to 350px in your css.

Check main.css line 539 and set height to Auto.